# AttributeError in python unit-test circle

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have to make unit-test for circle in python, but for the life of me cant figure out why I am getting this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Domaci\Preadvanje 8\circle_unittest.py", line 6, in test_area
self.assertEqual(circle.area (2),12.564)
File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Domaci\Preadvanje 8\class_circle.py", line 5, in area
return (self.radius * self.radius) * 3.141
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'radius'

Code for circle :

```
class circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
    def area(self):
        return (self.radius * self.radius) * 3.141
    def perimeter(self):
        
        return (2 * self.radius) * 3.141     
r = int(input("Input r: "))
newcircle = circle(r)  
print ("Area of the circle is: ", newcircle.area())
print("Perimeter of the circle is: ", newcircle.perimeter())
```

Code for test:

```
import unittest
from unittest.case import TestCase
from class_circle import circle
class test_circle(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_area(self):
        self.assertEqual(circle.area (2),12.564)
    def test_perimeter(self):
        self.assertEqual(circle.perimeter(2), 12.564)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the method "area" directly without instantiating a new object.

```
class test_circle(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_area(self):
        c = circle(2)
        self.assertEqual(c.area (2),12.564)
    def test_perimeter(self):
        c = circle(2)
        self.assertEqual(c.perimeter(2), 12.564)
```

In the above code, we create a circle called "c" first, and then test the method area on it, which fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you mate!!! Only thing is that c.area() should be without arguments in brackets.